# Does POSIX shell (dash) officially support named character classes?

Tags: bash, dash-shell

I know bash supports the so-called "named character classes" of patterns, such as [:alnum:], [:alpha:], [:ascii:] and [:digit:], but what about POSIX shell (typically dash in Ubuntu)? At least in the latest LTS Ubuntu distro (20.04) "man dash" doesn't mention those character classes at all which would suggest no support for them. However, my tests prove that they are at least partially and/or unofficially supported by dash. Here's a short example to prove my point:

```
dash #invoke the shell
mkdir 1 #create a directory whose name is a single digit
cd [[:digit:]] #change current directory to one whose name consists of a single digit
```

Assuming "1" is the only subdirectory in the current directory whose name consists of a single digit, the last line above will successfully match "1" and change the current directory to it. So what's the current status of support for named character classes in dash? If they indeed are supported, why are they skipped in dash manual? If they are not meant to be supported, why does my example work? Is it a flaw in manual or is it some undocumented feature/extension in recent dash versions?

Comment: You can report a bug on launchpad against the documentation.

Comment: its described in `man re_format`